# How to fix the error: Cannot assign to read only property 'room' of object '[object Object]'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
    let data = [{
        name: 'juan',
        age: 16,
        room: {
            num: 1,
            section: { id: 1, name: 'emerald' }
        }
    },{
        name: 'cruz',
        age: 18,
        room: {
            num: 2
        }
    }];
    let section = { id: 1, name: 'emerald' };
 

    const index = data.findIndex((x) => {
          if (x.room['section']) {
            if (x.room['section'].id === section.id) {
              return true;
            }
            return false;
          }
        });
    
     const obj = { ...data[index].room };
        delete obj.section;
         data[index].room = obj; // Cannot assign to read only property 'room' of object '[object Object]'
    
    console.log(data);
```

How to fix the error `Cannot assign to read only property 'room' of object '[object Object]'`.

after clicking the save the error appear and the deleting section is working. but from the line `data[index].room = obj;` it doesn't work. the error will appear which is the `Cannot assign to read only property 'room' of object '[object Object]'`

Comment: You're trying to remove whole `room` object ?

Comment: @ShawnVn I'm trying to remove the ```section```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
let data = [
    {
      name: 'juan',
      age: 16,
      room: {
          num: 1,
          section: { id: 1, name: 'emerald' }
          }
    },
    {
      name: 'cruz',
      age: 18,
      room: {
          num: 2
      }
    }
];

const section = { id: 1, name: 'emerald' };

const index = data.findIndex((x)=>{
     if(x.room.section)
         if(x.room.section.id === section.id)
              return true
     return false
});

delete data[index].room.section
console.log(data)
```

If somehow the code above did'nt solve your problem you can try something like this

```js
let data = [
        {
          name: 'juan',
          age: 16,
          room: {
              num: 1,
              section: { id: 1, name: 'emerald' }
              }
        },
        {
          name: 'cruz',
          age: 18,
          room: {
              num: 2
          }
        }
    ];

const section = { id: 1, name: 'emerald' };

const newArray = data.map(x=>{
  if(x.room.section)
    if(x.room.section.id === section.id)
       delete x.room.section
   return x    
});
//or
const newArray2 = data.map(x=>{
  if(x.room.section)
    if(x.room.section.id === section.id)
       return {...x,room:{num:room.num}}
   return x    
});

console.log(newArray);
console.log(newArray2);
```

Comment: ```Cannot delete property 'section' of [object Object]```

Comment: @BeginnerCoder I've updated my answer, check out does it works now

Comment: @BeginnerCoder Btw I've noticed that you've had a syntax error in your `data` array right after `num:1` in `0` index of it, you didn't put `,` after it. I don't know that was a typo or not but make sure to check if there is the same issue in your main code.

Comment: There's an error from the ```data['index'].room = obj```. ERROR: ```Cannot assign to read only property 'room' of object '[object Object]'```

Comment: @BeginnerCoder Can you show us a bit more of your code, because you haven't put `const`, `var` or `let` before neither of your variables. if you don't do that, you will declare those as `global` variables so ... anyway, is that a typo or something else?
Because the code is working here (press `Run code snippet` to see the result)

Comment: It run here, but when I try to applied on my code. it doesn't work after clicking the save it appear the error

Comment: @BeginnerCoder We need more information, please update your question with more info

Comment: @BeginnerCoder check out my updated answer, I hope it will help you.

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot delete property 'room' of [object Object]

Comment: @BeginnerCoder what about now? :(

Answer (score 0):

The condition to get index should be:

`let index = data.findIndex(x => x.room?.section?.id === section.id);`

```js
let data = [{
    name: 'juan',
    age: 16,
    room: {
        num: 1,
        section: { id: 1, name: 'emerald' }
    }
},{
    name: 'cruz',
    age: 18,
    room: {
        num: 2,
    }
}];

let section = { id: 1, name: 'emerald' };


let index = data.findIndex(x => x.room?.section?.id === section.id);
console.log('Found at index: ' + index);

delete data[index].room.section

console.log('Updated data: ');
console.log(data);
```

Comment: ```Cannot delete property 'section' of [object Object]```